# XML HTTP Request not working in event handler functions

Tags: javascript, event-handling, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to load weather data using a simple http request.  The actual request is set up properly, as it works perfectly when not called, but rather when the program just runs it upon loading.  However, when I place the code in a function called from an onclick or onsubmit event, the readyStatus foes directly to 4, and the status code stays at 0, and that is it.  The request does not get executed.  Is there something I do not know about setting up an http request in an event handler function?  Or is there a mistake in this work that I have not realized. The relevant code is directly below:

```
    <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="city">City: </label>
        <input type="city" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="Enter City">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="state">State: </label>
        <input type="state" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="Enter State">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-info" id="submit" onclick="get_data()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the get_data function, where the http request is set up, is below:

```
function get_data(){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/31c6aa45ad6072ac/conditions/q/MA/Boston.json", true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert(request.readyState);
        alert(request.status);
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
```

Comment: `readyState == 4` and `status == 200`

Comment: are you sure that endpoint is reachable and giving json?

Comment: Code plz not an image.  Im not typing in that url to test the json endpoint, happy to copy/paste though.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it to put the actual code in!

Comment: @Dinesh Yes, it works perfectly when not called in an event handling function

Comment: Where are you running this code? Local machine, Codepen, etc?

Comment: @mattgreen I'm running it on my local machine, just on a localhost

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but you checked your browser console, and do not see the response? The  reason I ask, is because you are using `alert` on the other 2 pieces of data. Are you seeing an error in the console?

Comment: @mattgreen Yes, I was using console.log earlier before the alert

Answer (score 1):

Mixed content warning with the current code.  Changing the url from http to https solves it.  Check this snippet, the http button and the https button change the url from/to https.  The problem exhibited from http match your reported issue.

```js
function get_data(s){
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    url = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/31c6aa45ad6072ac/conditions/q/MA/Boston.json";
    if (s) url = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/31c6aa45ad6072ac/conditions/q/MA/Boston.json";

    request.open("GET", url, true);

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        alert(request.readyState);
        alert(request.status);
        if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
        }
    }
    request.send();
}
```

```html
<button onclick='get_data()'>http</button>
<button onclick='get_data(1)'>https</button>
```

Comment: hmm, thanks for the suggestion but that still doesn't seem to execute the request.

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the button, and changed the alerts to console.log(s) on jsbin, and it's working properly (IMO):

```
function get_data() {
  console.log('running');
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://api.wunderground.com/api/31c6aa45ad6072ac/conditions/q/MA/Boston.json", true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        console.log(request.readyState);
        console.log(request.status);
        request.readyState == 4 &&
        request.status == 200 &&
        console.log(request.responseText);
    }
    request.send();
}
```

`<button onclick="get_data()">Submit</button>`

http://jsbin.com/cegifi/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Any idea why it would work for you on Jsbin, but not for me locally? @mattgreen

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Try the code from jsbin on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, it was the fact that the button was of type submit and not button, so that it would resubmit the page with false information.  Thanks for everyone's help!!